# How to find methods that are not annotated with return void

Tags: php, regex

This is something for regexp lovers :)

FLOW3's Code Convention claim that you should annotate methods that do not return anything with @return void:

```
/**
 * A method
 *
 * @return void
 */
```

I keep forgetting it and want to regexp with netbeans for all methods that I've missed ...

So far i got

```
\*\s[^@return]+.*(\n)\s.\*/
```

Which does not work really well:

```
/**
 * Method that gets matched.
 *
 * @param string $comment
 */
public function aMethod() {
    // Some Code
}

/**
 * A method that does not get matched and shouldn't.
 *
 * @param string $test
 * @return void
 */
public function anotherMethod($test) {
    // Some Code
}


/**
 * A variable that get's matched but should not
     * be matched.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $var;

/**
 * Why is this method getting matched?
 *
 * @return void
 */
private function thirdMethod() {
        // Code
    }
```

How would you match this?

Here's an [example](http://regexpal.com/?flags=&regex=%5C%2a%5Cs%5B%5E@return%5D%2b.%2a%28%5Cn%29%5Cs.%5C%2a/&input=%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20/%2a%2a%0A%09%20%2a%20Method%20that%20gets%20matched.%0A%09%20%2a%0A%09%20%2a%20@param%20string%20%24comment%0A%09%20%2a/%0A%09public%20function%20aMethod%28%29%20%7B%0A%09%09//%20Some%20Code%0A%09%7D%0A%0A%09/%2a%2a%0A%09%20%2a%20A%20method%20that%20does%20not%20get%20matched%20and%20shouldn%27t.%0A%09%20%2a%0A%09%20%2a%20@param%20string%20%24test%0A%09%20%2a%20@return%20void%0A%09%20%2a/%0A%09public%20function%20anotherMethod%28%24test%29%20%7B%0A%09%09//%20Some%20Code%0A%09%7D%0A%0A%0A%09/%2a%2a%0A%09%20%2a%20A%20variable%20that%20get%27s%20matched%20but%20should%20not%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2a%20be%20matched.%0A%09%20%2a%0A%09%20%2a%20@var%20string%0A%09%20%2a/%0A%09protected%20%24var;%0A%0A%09/%2a%2a%0A%09%20%2a%20Why%20is%20this%20method%20getting%20matched?%0A%09%20%2a%0A%09%20%2a%20@return%20void%0A%09%20%2a/%0A%09private%20function%20thirdMethod%28%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20//%20Code%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D) in a regexp tester:

Comment: this is a javascript code right? so void functions might end with any empty return or no return at all?

Comment: It's PHP. The actual implementation does not matter in this case, as I just want to search the comments.

However: void means no return at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A negative lookbehind assertion might help:

```
\*\s*@[a-z]+(?<!return)\s+.+\s*\*/\s*(?:public|protected|private)?\s+function
```

This will match any function which does not have @return as the last line of the docblock. It might have some false positives, i.e. where a @return is there but not on the last line, but it's a good start.

Note that this doesn't work in Regex tester because JavaScript doesn't support the lookbehind assertion. [Here's an example](http://codepad.viper-7.com/5bBWhc).

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know that lookarounds did not work in Javascript, maybe that's why I failed, because I tried, but it didn't work in the regexp tester.

Comment: Hm. It does not recognize my missing @return voids in netbeans, but I guess it's because lookarounds are buggy (http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=181878). Thank you so much for your input.

Comment: Have you considered using something like [PHP_CodeSniffer](http://pear.php.net/package/PHP_CodeSniffer)? Typo3 seem to have [their own sniffs](http://forge.typo3.org/projects/team-forge/wiki/The_sniffs_with_code_examples#Comments), but the specific one you're after is lacking. the Squiz FunctionCommentSniff does address this though.

Comment: Thanks, I was not aware of that!